# Many versions of JDK: How do I specify which one is used?

Tags: java, ant, build, compilation

I have installed many versions of the JDK: `1.4.2, 1.5 and 1.6`.
How do I specify which version of the JDK is used when compiling using Ant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two solutions:

- Specify the full path in your command:
  for example `/opt/java/jdk16/bin/javac ...` on Linux
- Use the `-source` and `-target` arguments of the javac command. This allows you specify the source code level and targeted JRE version

Also note:

- Some Linux distributions can include tools to specify which JDK version to use by default.
- Using `-source` and `-target` checkes that your language constructs are compliant with the targeted runtime, but does NOT check that core classes are compatible. This means that compiling with `-source 1.4` on a JDK 1.6 will be just fine, even if you use `String.isEmpty()` which appeared in Java 6. This might lead to errors at runtime

Answer (score 1):

```
javac -source 1.4 -target 1.4 YourFile.java
```

> -source release
>       Specifies the version of source code accepted. The following
>   values for release are allowed:
>       1.3   the compiler does not support assertions, generics, or other
>   language features introduced after JDK 1.3.
>       1.4   the compiler accepts code containing assertions, which were
>   introduced in JDK 1.4.
>       1.5   the compiler accepts code containing generics and other
>   language features introduced in JDK 5. The compiler defaults to the
>   version 5 behavior if the -source flag is not used.
>       5     Synonym for 1.5

Here is the relevant documentation.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Ant `<javac>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)`<source>` and/or `<target>` attributes. Valid values can be from 1.1 to 1.7, with 5, 6, and 7 valid aliases for 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7. Also, the `<executable>` attribute can be used to set which java javac compiler is used.  For example:

```
<javac source="1.4" target="1.4" executable="c:\java1.6\bin\javac.exe"/>
```